# How do I prevent the legend to be cut off on angular-google-chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-visualization

I am following example for showing google bar chart using angular-google-chart from [here](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/examples/bar/). As you can see from the image below, my label, legends is hidden partially. How Do I showing a full text?

[image]

Here is the code:

```
angular.module("google-chart-sample", ["googlechart", "googlechart-docs"])
.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";

    $scope.onions = [
        {v: "Onions"},
        {v: 3},
    ];

    $scope.chartObject.data = {"cols": [
        {id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string"},
        {id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number"}
    ], "rows": [
        {c: [
            {v: "Mushrooms"},
            {v: 3},
        ]},
        {c: $scope.onions},
        {c: [
            {v: "Olives"},
            {v: 31}
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Zucchini"},
            {v: 1},
        ]},
        {c: [
            {v: "Pepperoni"},
            {v: 2},
        ]}
    ]};

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night'
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to prevent legend labels being cut off you could set `chartArea` property:

> An object with members to configure the placement and size of the
>   chart area (where the chart itself is drawn, excluding axis and
>   legends). Two formats are supported: a number, or a number followed by
>   %. A simple number is a value in pixels; a number followed by % is a
>   percentage. `Example:
>   chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:'50%',height:'75%'}`
>
> Type: object
>   Default: null

**Example**

```js
angular.module("google-chart-sample", ["googlechart"])
.controller("GenericChartCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.chartObject = {};

    $scope.chartObject.type = "BarChart";


    $scope.chartObject.data = {
        "cols": [
            { id: "t", label: "Topping", type: "string" },
            { id: "s", label: "Slices", type: "number" }
        ], "rows": [
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Mushrooms" },
                   { v: 3 },
                ]
            },
            { c:  [
                   { v: "Onions" },
                   { v: 3 },
                  ] 
            },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Olives" },
                   { v: 31 }
                ]
            },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Zucchini" },
                   { v: 1 },
                ]
            },
            {
                c: [
                   { v: "Pepperoni" },
                   { v: 2 },
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    $scope.chartObject.options = {
        'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
        chartArea: {  width: "60%" }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.18/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-chart/0.0.11/ng-google-chart.js"></script>
<div ng-app="google-chart-sample" ng-controller="GenericChartCtrl">
    <div google-chart chart="chartObject" style="height:600px; width:480px;"></div>
</div>
```